# Apps Script Frame Error in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, google-apps-script

I have successfully coded a script and embedded it into my Google Site.  The script works fine  in Chrome and Safari, but I receive the "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" error within IE, even though I've added the script using Google's instructions with the Apps Script Gadget.  Looking at my code, is there a specific part of this code that causes the security issue with IE and denies it being displayed?  The code loads a spreadsheet into a chart with tabs (it's a big spreadsheet so I subdivided it into tabs) and then the user can filter based on a few different fields.  Is there a workaround to this?

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var ssID = '0AhiXAz5qhL4TdERkNFJndkVXd1A3T0xYdHlnMkp3U2c';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = dataRange.getNumRows();
  var numCols = dataRange.getNumColumns();
  var dataTable = sheet.getRange(1, 4, numRows, numCols - 3).getDataTable();

  // Filters
  var locationFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
    .setDataTable(dataTable)
    .setFilterColumnLabel('Where was your role located?')
    .setAllowMultiple(true)
    .setSortValues(true)
    .setLabelStacking(Charts.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    .setCaption('Choose a location')
    .setSortValues(true)
    .build();
  var functionFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
    .setDataTable(dataTable)
    .setFilterColumnLabel('In what function was your role?')
    .setAllowMultiple(true)
    .setSortValues(true)
    .setLabelStacking(Charts.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    .setCaption('Choose a function')
    .setSortValues(true)
    .build();
   var titleFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
    .setDataTable(dataTable)
    .setFilterColumnLabel('What was the role title?')
    .setAllowMultiple(true)
    .setSortValues(true)
    .setLabelStacking(Charts.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    .setCaption('Choose a title')
    .setSortValues(true)
    .build();
  var numberFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
    .setDataTable(dataTable)
    .setFilterColumnLabel('Which placement was the role?')
    .setAllowMultiple(true)
    .setSortValues(true)
    .setLabelStacking(Charts.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    .setCaption('Choose a placement number')
    .setSortValues(true)
    .build();


  // Build individual tab charts
  // Tab 1: Role Specific
  var dataViewDef1 = Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
  var chart1 = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(dataTable).setOption('width', '100%').setOption('height', '100%').setDataViewDefinition(dataViewDef1).build();

  // Tab 2: Training
  var dataViewDef2 = Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11]);
  var chart2 = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(dataTable).setOption('width', '100%').setOption('height', '100%').setDataViewDefinition(dataViewDef2).build();

  // Tab 3: Line Manager
  var dataViewDef3 = Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 12, 13]);
  var chart3 = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(dataTable).setOption('width', '100%').setOption('height', '100%').setDataViewDefinition(dataViewDef3).build();

  // Tab 4: Development Tools
  var dataViewDef4 = Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 14, 15]);
  var chart4 = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(dataTable).setOption('width', '100%').setOption('height', '100%').setDataViewDefinition(dataViewDef4).build();

  // Tab 5: Culture, Visas, and Moves
  var dataViewDef5 = Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 16, 17]);
  var chart5 = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(dataTable).setOption('width', '100%').setOption('height', '100%').setDataViewDefinition(dataViewDef5).build();

  // Create GUI
  var tabPanel = app.createTabPanel();
  var vpanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setSpacing(10);
  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setId('scroll').setSize('100%', '100%');

  tabPanel.add(chart1, 'Role Specific').add(chart2, 'Training').add(chart3, 'Line Manager').add(chart4, 'Development').add(chart5, 'Culture');
  tabPanel.selectTab(0);
  vpanel.add(locationFilter).add(functionFilter).add(titleFilter).add(numberFilter).add(tabPanel);

  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(dataTable).bind([locationFilter, functionFilter, titleFilter, numberFilter], [chart1, chart2, chart3, chart4, chart5]).build();

  dashboard.add(vpanel);

  app.add(dashboard);

  return app;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot might help. But based on the description of the error message in question, you see this when the server sends an `X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY` or `X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SameOrigin` header to prevent framing.

This header is used to combat ClickJacking attacks.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx for details.

Comment: Hi @EricLaw,Thanks for the information.  I've attached a screen shot here: http://imagesup.net/?di=1513770228488.  I've done some more research and noticed that the Insert > Apps Script by default puts the Apps Script in an iframe (by clicking on View Source you can see this on a site), so there isn't a way to NOT have it in an iframe.  Right now I have loaded the GAS into a new page to display in IE, which is a viable workaround except that you lose the titles and navigation so really, not ideal.

Comment: Yes, this is the X-Frame-Options block page. You can use Fiddler or another network debugger to look at the exact HTTP header value sent.

Answer (score 0):

An experimental script-gadget in a google-sites that works fine on Chrome gave me the frame error message when running on IE11 on a diffent computer.
Then I realized that I was signed in with a different google account on that computer, and that I published the script gadget for "only me".
I changed this setting to "anyone" in the "deploy as web app" publish menu.
**Now, my script works fine in IE11 without the frame error.**